# How figurative can 姿 be?

Tags: usage

I've always thought of `姿` as a physical form or shape, but I came across this passage from my book:

> 彼らの話から浮かびあがってきたのは、・・・・・{この人}の**姿**だった。

(I took just took out some descriptions of the woman they're talking about that aren't really relevant [that I can tell, anyway].)

I imagine that I've got the meaning of the sentence--that these guys are talking about this person--but what exactly does `姿` here represent? In the story, these guys are trying to track down a woman, but at this point they haven't seen actually seen her, only heard about her from rumors, etc.. Is `姿`　this sort of *image* they have of her? Is it sort of a representation of who she is, and not her physical person?

More importantly, is this a common usage of `姿`　or more literary?

Comment: This usage is quite usual and not particularly literary.  I hope that other people can explain it better, but in the meanwhile, see sense 3 and the second example of sense 5 in [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%81%9F&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0na).

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito, your link is dead

Answer (score 6):

[This is meant to be a practical rather an academic answer, intended for fellow students]

As the above comment helpfully says, the usage you found is not particularly unusual or literary.

I can't comment on how *extreme* the use of 姿 gets in a literary context but *if, like me, you are trying to grasp the breadth of its normal use over and above its familiar use as "figure" or "appearance"* then I think the easiest way  is know a few key sentences (or at least this is what I am doing). I made a point of remembering and then focus on grasping the following few:

> 本来の姿  | proper state / real character
>
> 母の姿が目に浮かぶ | my late mother comes to mind (note context)
>
> 〜姿を見せる｜appear on the scene

And, as it was an important word to understand, being alert for new/variations on these.

I put the following list together using some more of my own examples and the Apple dictionary (which seems close to Daijisen in content)

**1 外見，身なり/appearance:**

> 男の子はみすぼらしい姿をしていた｜The boy was shabbily dressed.
>
> ___________________に姿をやつす｜disguise oneself as_______

**2 体の格好/figure**

> 母の姿が目に浮かぶ | my late mother comes to mind (note context)
>
> トムは後ろ姿がジムにそっくりだ｜When seen from behind, Tom looks exactly like Jim.

**3 人の目に映る体，その人/"sightings of a person"**

> あれっきり彼は姿を見せない｜We have seen nothing of him since. /That was the last we saw of him.
>
> 彼は姿を隠した［くらました］｜He went into hiding.

**4  物の形/shape of an object**

> 間もなく湖が姿を現した｜Soon the lake showed itself [came in view].
>
> 太陽が何日も姿を見せなかった｜The sun remained [stayed] hidden for days.

**5  ありさま，様子/condition, circumstances**

> 本来の姿  | proper state / real character
>
> それが民主国家の本当の姿だ｜That is what a democratic country should be like.

Comment: (1) You forgot to _answer_ the specific question that is being asked.  (2) If you copied these definitions and examples from something, I think that you should cite the source.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I have amended my answer in response to your comments (thanks). Please bear in mind I am trying to share what I think the OP might find useful based on my own experience. I may be wrong but others can also contribute too.

Comment: The line break didn't work on the second example under #3.  A not-well-known trick is to add two spaces to the end of a line before you hit the Return key, and the next line will show up immediately underneath, which might be what you wanted.

Comment: @Troyen: Thanks. I've been struggling with that function.

Comment: 結局コピペしただけじゃん。OPでもできた。